# How to append multiple background images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to load images as backgrounds/fill on my nodes on a graph, each node has its own ID and there are endpoints that if you parse the ID return the correct image for that particular node.

I want to parse the nodes ID and load a background image this way, the only method that works with my code that i have found is to first append a 'pattern' on my nodes which contains a URL, and then reference this when appending my nodes. I can't figure out how I can iterate and do this by the ID of my nodes, this ID should pull the correct Image!

the code:

```
addCircleNodes(onClick: (node: EngagementGraphNode) => void): void {
var img_url = `https://jimjamsDoughnuts/ID-12345/standard`
const circle = this.group
  .selectAll('circle.node')
  .data(this.nodes)
  .enter();
circle
  .append("pattern")
  .attr("id", "insightImage")
  .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", img_url)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 1)
  .attr("height", 1)
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
circle
  .filter(node => node.depth !== 0)
  .append('circle')
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
  .style('fill', node => `url(#insightImage)`)
  .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
  .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
  .on('click', node => onClick(node));
```

So at the moment the result is that every single one of my nodes successfully loads this same image, I have tried a function(d) method with the img_url and img_id but I havent figured out how to parse my own node.id because what I really want to do somehow is be able to call the url and say "jimjamsdoughnuts/node.id/standard"

possibly like        node = > "jimjamddoughnuts${node.id}/standard"
but calling that above does not work! it only works after I first append a pattern, for the life of me I dont know why!

There is this resource I found online which deals with iterating through the elements and adding the image but i couldnt quite figure out how to incorporate my own node.id into it: http://bl.ocks.org/SpaceActuary/25e72aadac28f2c87667816e82c609db

Thanks so much if you can help.

Comment: What is `node.id` and is that `id` value coming from the data?

Comment: node.id is the ID of each node on my graph, so each node represents something such as a product or an engagement. Because we can call on the class via the top: node: EngagementGraphNode... the node.id can be taken. it's this that I want to parse into the url

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: The data from the nodes is an instance of the class export abstract class EngagementGraphNode {
  public endpoint: string;
  public id: string;
  public name: string; .... (more vars)... } and the URL is just a standard url which includes the nodes id

Comment: So the url is already in the data?

Comment: the URL is just an external site that is linked to the project so the nodes on my graph which each have an ID, have an image that is hosted externally and I can call on that URL and parse the {node.id} and the image can be accessed/retrieved, im struggling on how to iterate through the nodes and do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187851/discussion-between-ksav-and-sparlarva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The D3 convention is that callback functions are passed the element’s datum (typically called *d*), the element’s index (*i*), and the array of elements (nodes). The element itself is *this*.

So pass a callback function as the value of `.attr()` to get to the bound datum (d). Once you have the datum it is as simple as returning the formed url string with `d.someProperty`.

But as you are dynamically creating a unique `<pattern>` for each `<circle>`, you need to give each `<pattern>` it's own unique ID, and then reference that unique `<pattern>` using its own unique ID (otherwise each `<circle>` is being filled by the same static `<pattern>`, OR you are just creating multiple patterns with the same ID).

```
addCircleNodes(onClick: (node: EngagementGraphNode) => void): void {
var img_url = `https://jimjamsDoughnuts/ID-12345/standard`
const circle = this.group
  .selectAll('circle.node')
  .data(this.nodes)
  .enter();
circle
  .append("pattern")
  .attr("id", d => `insightImage-${d.id}`)
  .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", d => `https://jimjamsDoughnuts/${d.id}/standard`)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 1)
  .attr("height", 1)
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
circle
  .filter(node => node.depth !== 0)
  .append('circle')
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
  .style('fill', d => `url(#insightImage-${d.id})`)
  .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
  .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
  .on('click', node => onClick(node));
```